# jQuery Validate: deactivate validation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

On a webpage I have two forms that I validate with jQuery Validate. The user can decide if he needs to fill out a form or not. If he decides he does not need it, I want the validation to be deactivated.

**Fiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/eLrxj3gh/8/

Here comes my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <form class="simple-form" action="" method="post">   
      <input type="checkbox" id="mark-as-not-needed-1" class="mark-as-not-needed"><label for="mark-as-not-needed-1">not needed</label>

      <div class="form-errors"></div>   

      <input name="field1" type="text"></input>   
      <input name="field2" type="text"></input>   

      <input type="submit" value="submit form #1"></input>   
  </form>   

  <form class="simple-form" action="" method="post">   
      <input type="checkbox" id="mark-as-not-needed-1" class="mark-as-not-needed"><label for="mark-as-not-needed-1">not needed</label>

      <div class="form-errors"></div>   

      <input name="field1" type="text"></input>   
      <input name="field2" type="text"></input>   

      <input type="submit" value="submit form #2"></input>   
  </form>
```

**JS:**

```
          $('.simple-form').each(function () {   
              var $currentForm = $(this);   
              $currentForm.validate(   
                      {   
                          debug: true,   
                          rules: {   
                              field1: {   
                                  required: true   
                              },   
                              field2: {   
                                  required: true   
                              }   
                          },   
                          submitHandler: function (form) {   
                              $(form).find('.form-errors').empty();   

                              alert('submitted');   
                          },   
                          showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {   
                              var msgerror = "Fill out all fields of this form.";   
                              var divErrors = $currentForm.find('.form-errors');   
                              if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {   
                                  divErrors.empty().html(msgerror).show();   
                              } else {   
                                  divErrors.hide();   
                              }   
                              this.defaultShowErrors();   
                          },   
                          errorPlacement: function (error, element) {   
                              return false;   
                          },   
                          errorClass: "form-invalid"   
                      }   
              );   
          });   

          $('.simple-form').each(function () {   
              if (!($(this).valid())) {   
                  console.log('Page load: one form is NOT valid');   
              }   
          });
```

I already tried using `$('.simple-form')[0].submit()` as suggested in another post, but it does not work.

So my question: How do I achieve that for a form for which a user clicks "not needed" its validation gets deactivated and all error messages and styles disappear for this form?

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have add a condition to check whether user checked the **not needed** checkbox or not.

I have edited jsfiddle accordingly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eLrxj3gh/13/)

like the following condition

```
 if($currentForm.find(".mark-as-not-needed").prop('checked') != true)
```

Comment: This is the original fiddle link, not a new one.

Answer (score 0):

i leave your code as it is and tried to see if the checkbox is checked, it will write the property *formNoValidate* into the input fields - i found this in the .validate docs ... but it is not working as i thought

https://jsfiddle.net/eLrxj3gh/11/

calling functions depending on the state of the checkbox

```
$('.mark-as-not-needed').on('click', function(){
 if(this.checked === true) {
        deactivate_validation(this.id);
    }
    else {
        activate_validation(this.id);
    }

});
```

looking for the right form, search for input type=text elements and add a property to each one (i saw different styles of this prop in the console.log)

```
function deactivate_validation(el) {
    $checkbox = $('#'+el);
    $inputs = $checkbox.parent().find('input:text');
    $inputs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop("formNoValidate", true);
        $(this).prop("formnovalidate", true);
        console.log($(this));
    });
}

function activate_validation(el) {
    $checkbox = $('#'+el);
    $inputs = $checkbox.parent().find('input:text');
    $inputs.each(function(){
        $(this).prop("formNoValidate", false);
        $(this).prop("formnovalidate", false);
        console.log($(this));
    });
}
```

in console.log i see that the property was written correctly to the input field ... but .validate() wont look for this prop ... why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

HTML:

```
          <form class="simple-form" action="" method="post">   

                 <input type="checkbox" id="mark-as-not-needed-1" name="mark-as-not-needed-1" class="mark-as-not-needed"><label for="mark-as-not-needed-1">not needed</label>


          <div class="form-errors"></div>   

          <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text"></input>   
          <input id="field2" name="field2" type="text"></input>   

          <input type="submit" value="submit form #1"></input>   
      </form>   

      <br>
      <br>
      <form class="simple-form" action="" method="post">   
          <input type="checkbox" id="mark-as-not-needed-2" name="mark-as-not-needed-2" class="mark-as-not-needed"><label for="mark-as-not-needed-1">not needed</label>

          <div class="form-errors"></div>   

          <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text"></input>   
          <input id="field2" name="field2" type="text"></input>   

          <input type="submit" value="submit form #2"></input>   

      </form>
```

JS:

```
$('.simple-form').on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", 
  var divErrors = $(this).parent().find('.form-errors');
  if(this.checked) {
     removeRules(checkrule);
     divErrors.hide();    
     $(this).parent().find("input[type='text']").removeAttr('class');
  } else {
     addRules(checkrule);
     divErrors.show();  
     $(this).parent().find("input[type='text']").attr('class','form-invalid');
  }
 });

var checkrule = {
 field1: {   
         required: true   
         },   
 field2: {   
         required: true   
         }   
 };

function addRules(
  for (var item in rulesObj){
   $('#'+item).rules('add',rulesObj[item]); 
  } 
}

function removeRules(
  for (var item in rulesObj){
    $('#'+item).rules('remove');
  } 
}

$('.simple-form').each(function () {   
              var $currentForm = $(this);   
              $currentForm.validate(   
                      {   
                          debug: true,   
                          rules: checkrule,   
                          submitHandler: function (form) {   
                              $(form).find('.form-errors').empty();   

                              alert('submitted');   
                          },   
                          showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {   
                              var msgerror = "Fill out all fields of this    form.";   
                              var divErrors = $currentForm.find('.form-errors');   
                              if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {   
                                  divErrors.empty().html(msgerror).show();   
                              } else {   
                                  divErrors.hide();   
                              }   
                              this.defaultShowErrors();   
                          },   
                          errorPlacement: function (error, element) {   
                              return false;   
                          },   
                          errorClass: "form-invalid"   
                      }   
              );   
          });   

          $('.simple-form').each(function () {   
              if (!($(this).valid())) {   
                  console.log('Page load: one form is NOT valid');   
              }   
          });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXwaEj